# Flutter: iOS notification background handler

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to handle iOS background notification click_action when it is null ?

```
{
 "to" : "abcd1234",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "title": "Testing",
     "body" : "Testing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
 },
 "data" : {
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
     "route": "/Home",
 }
}
```

```
onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isAndroid ? BackgroundHandler.backgroundHandler : null
```

This [post](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1695) mentioned *onBackgroundMessage not implemented in iOS just use for android*. Is there a way to handle in iOS ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If you did all the ios firebase configurations using XCode, you can use the native swift functions to listen to the background notifications on iOS.

Inside your `AppDelegate` class,

```
 override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                              fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        /// Here you will get the silent background notification .
        /// May be you can call you flutter code from here if you need.
        /// Make sure that you end your processing quickly, else you will not get the background notification regularly and timely from iOS.


        /// After you completed, make sure you call the completionHandler so that iOS knows you are done with your background task and you completed it so quickly.

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        
    }
```

FlutterFire team is working on this to bring to the flutter side and you can expect this very soon I think by looking at their GitHub PRs.

Comment: May I know what's the different with this 2 function ? As you can see the second function got a completionHandler().

Comment: Im not sure but I think that if you have data to fetch from the remote notification, i.e., the content-availble set to true, the one with completionHandler will get called. The other may be for normal notification handling. Please read docs for clarity.